# I have a question about how s3 intelligent-tiering works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I looked at the AWS documentation on intelligence tiering, but there is some confusion.

Could you please confirm that I understand correctly?

1. If I change the object's storage class to intelligence tiering, the object will only be stored as either [frequency] or [Infrequent]. In this case, there is no performance degradation, so the system is not significantly affected.
2. If I set "intelligence tiering archive config" in the bucket configuration, only objects whose storage class is intelligence tiering will be archived.
   Archived data can take hours to reload and can affect your system.

Did I understand correctly?

Comment: You can read [how S3 Intelligent-Tiering works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intelligent-tiering-overview.html).